# Handling event using custom data attributes or binding data to the handler?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using React, but this is not necessarily a React specific question.

Is there a major difference between grabbing a custom data attribute in an event handler

```
<MyElement greeting="hello" farewell="goodbye" />

//MyElement component
handleClick(event) {    
  console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.myData);
}
...
<li data-my-data={this.props.greeting} onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Greeting</li>
<li data-my-data={this.props.farewell} onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Farewell</li>
```

and binding a value to the event handler

```
<MyElement greeting="hello" farewell="goodbye" />

//MyElement component
handleClick(myData) {
  console.log(myData);
}
...
<li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.greeting)}>Click Greeting</li>
<li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.farewell)}>Click Farewell</li>
```

Is this just a matter of personal preference or are there actual pros and cons to each of these?

Comment: First option is going to safe. No one is having access to modify that. But second option people can mistakenly change the values.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it is a matter of personal preference AND there are Pro's and Con's to each solution.
IMHO Option 1 is a shortcut around react design principles, which can get you in a lot of trouble later on.

**PRO Option 1: 'store' the data in DOM dataset:**

- Less tedious binding stuff in your component
- dataset is also accessible from outside the react component; other components / code can directly read/ update dataset

**PRO Option 2: 'store' the data in react javascript component**

- Less worries if the target passed is the right DOM node. (`event.currentTarget` takes first higher up component with event listener, `event.target` takes clicked element)
- dataset is only accessible from inside react component, keeping your code cleaner

My personal preference is option 2: It forces you to stick to react dataflow and design principles, and keeps all relevant code in the same place, inside the javascript react component.

This safeguards you from the following route to hell (especially prevalent in larger projects and larger teams):

- new requirement: some remote component needs access to dataset
- the proper redesign of react component tree is tedious: you may need to move management of dataset to a higher component to give access to dataset, which means revision of react component tree.
- but a shortcut is available: the remote component can also read directly from DOM - so go for the quick and dirty solution
- new requirement: the original component needs an update
- now there is no way of finding out which other components actually read/ rely on the dataset, so your code has in effect become unmanageable.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're saying, but React could still be managing data in the first option.  The value for the custom data attribute could also be a variable in curly braces (e.g., props, state, etc).  Would you mind giving me an example of when `event.currentTarget` would not work as expected?  Any chance you meant `event.target`?

Comment: Updated my answer to explain further: the data is not stored in component, but in DOM. When component gets more structure, your `event.target` (or `event.currentTarget`) may not point the right DOM item, and can't access the data (ugly to debug). Biggest issue is probably that you create a backdoor to get access to data from outside the component, which opens up road to debugging nightmares.

Comment: I just updated my question to try and show what I was trying to say about React managing the data.  I know that the values will end up in the DOM when using the data attributes, but the elements will still be rendered when the props change, etc.  I understand what you're saying about `event.target`, that is why I used `event.currentTarget` so when a child of the `<li>` is clicked the correct dataset is used

Comment: Rewrote my answer. Both will work, but 2 keeps your code easier to maintain as your app grows.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, using ES6 arrow function:

```
<li onClick={()=>this.handleClick(this.props.greeting)}>Click Greeting</li>
```

This is cleaner and more efficient than `bind`, and requires much less code than option (1).

Only (potential) disadvantage is that in this case you create new function object every time during render(). Which will only be the problem when you're passing the callback to the custom component which is relying on shouldComponentUpdate() optimization. In this case, option (1) should work the best, as you should avoid dynamically created closures.